# запрет на использование system() и exec()

Tags: c++, python-3.x, безопасность, exec, systemd

Доброе время суток!
У меня есть проект на Python3.5, а именно система автоматического тестирования для локальной сети(тестер для олимпиадных задач по программированию).
Допустим кто-то сдает решение. А именно:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
   system("rm -rf /*")
   return 0;
}
```

или

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
   system("shutdown -a now")
   return 0;
}
```

Первый случай пофиксить я знаю как. Просто запускать программу от другого пользователя(файлы принадлежат admin, а запускать от пользователя tester)

А вот с вторым возникают затруднения.
Возможно можно решить проблему еще на стадии компиляции. Для компиляции используется g++.

Comment: но shutdown может выполнить только root ...

Comment: @Mike, хз. Ибо без root пк выключался. arch linux 32 bit и ubuntu 64 bit.

Comment: @Mike, проект запускался командой python -m project_name на директорию выше, без предоставления прав суперпользователя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Делаем небольшую программу на C:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   const char newroot[]="/path/to/test/dir";
   int main(int c, char **v, char **e) {
       int rc; const char *m;
       if ( (m="chdir" ,rc=chdir(newroot)) == 0
         && (m="chroot",rc=chroot(newroot)) == 0
         && (m="setuid",rc=setuid(getuid())) == 0 )
             m="execve", execve(v[1],v+2,e);
       perror(m);
       return 1;
   }
   ```
2. Компилируем ее, называем например `chrooter`
3. Делаем владельцем этой программы пользователя root: `sudo chown root.root chrooter`
4. Ставим на программу SUID бит, что бы она при запуске получала права рута (т.к. только root может выполнять функцию chroot): `sudo chmod 4755 chrooter`.
5. Кладем программу куда нибудь, откуда мы сможем ее запускать из своей питоновской программы.
6. Компилируем программу пользователя с ключом `-static` что бы она не требовала для работы никаких библиотек (либо придется выяснять какие библиотеки она использует и все их класть в `/path/to/test/dir/lib`.
7. После успешной компиляции копируем получившийся исполнимый файл в тестовый каталог (тот что указан в chrooter).
8. Запускаем программу (предположим она осталась a.out): `chrooter ./a.out параметры программы`

Программа при этом может использовать любые функции, включая system, exec и т.п. так же она может сама удалять файлы (для теста работоспособности я сделал программу выполняющую `unlink("abc"); unlink("../abc");` создал файлы abc в каталоге тестирования и на уровень выше с правами пользователя под которым запускал). НО программа находится в chroot, это означает что корнем файловой системы для данной программы является указанный нами каталог (`/path/to/test/dir`) и за его пределы она выйти не может. Таким образом тестовая программа удалит файл abc в тестовом каталоге, но никакого более верхнего каталога `../` для нее не существует. Так же программа фактически не сможет запустить с помощью system ни одну стандартную программу просто по тому, что для нее не существует каталогов /bin, /usr/bin где лежат эти самые команды. Если требуется что бы она что то могла запускать надо в ее каталоге создать /bin и положить туда нужные программы (не забыв положить в /lib требуемые им библиотеки)

P.S. в принципе конечно можно было бы не делать специальную программу пускатель, а воспользоватся стандартной командой `chroot /path/to/new/root program`, но команда chroot может выполнятся только рутом, а разрешать питоновскому пользователю использовать sudo для запуска chroot я не считаю надежным, вдруг в ней будут какие нибудь ошибки и пользователь извне сможет подменить выполняемую команду, например.